# How do I create a packaged_task with a member function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, packaged-task

On the program below, I'm trying to create a packaged_task with a member function:

```
#include <future>
using namespace std;

struct S
{
    int calc(int& a)
    {
        return a*a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    auto bnd = std::bind(&S::calc, s);
    std::packaged_task<int(int&)> task( bnd);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the attempt results in an error.

How can this be done?

Comment: The problem is not your use of `packaged_task`, it's your use of `bind`. Remove the `packaged_task` and try calling `bnd(1)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bind` is quirky.

Replace your use of `std::bind` with:

```
template<class T, class Sig>
struct bound_member;

template<class T, class R, class...Args>
struct bound_member<T, R(Args...)> {
  T* t;
  R(T::*m)(Args...);
  R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return (t->*m)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};

template<class T, class R, class...Args>
bound_member<T,R(Args...)> bind_member( T* t, R(T::*m)(Args...) ) {
  return {t,m};
}
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
bound_member<T,R(Args...)> bind_member( T& t, R(T::*m)(Args...) ) {
  return {&t,m};
}
template<class T, class R, class...Args>
bound_member<T,R(Args...)> bind_member( T&& t, R(T::*m)(Args...) )
=delete; // avoid lifetime issues?
```

and now `auto bnd = bind_member(s, S::calc);` should make your code work.

There are few situations where a lambda isn't a better idea than `std::bind`, especially by C++14.  In C++11, there are some corner cases, but even then I usually prefer to write my own binders without the quirks of `std::bind`.

Answer (score 3):

by adding up a placeholder like:

```
auto bnd = std::bind(&S::calc, s, std::placeholders::_1)
```